# How to quote/unquote variables for constructing formulas in R

Tags: r, metaprogramming, quoting

I am having a hard time understanding how quoting, unquoting, quasiquotation... works in R.
In this case I wanted to fit a linear model. I think ususally you do not need to quote the input to the `lm`-call.

So I wanted to do something like this:

```
names(mtcars)

y = "mpg" # response
x = "hp" # predictor

fml = y ~ x

lm(fml, data=mtcars)
```

But obviously this does not work as literally "y" and "x" are passed int the formula. I tried several things with `expr()` and `eval()` but I think I am not on the right way. Reading the chapter on Metaprogramming in advanced R would certainly help a lot, but maybe there is also an "intuitive" solution here.

Comment: `y = as.name("mpg"); x = as.name("hp"); fml = eval(bquote(.(y) ~ .(x)))` However, it's usually better to substitute into the `lm` call, e.g.,  `eval(bquote(lm(.(y) ~ .(x))))`, as otherwise you could run into scoping issues since the wrong environment could be associated with the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `lm` you don't need quoting/unquoting. You can use `as.formula` or `reformulate` to construct the formula.

```
lm(reformulate(y, x), data=mtcars)
```

However, since `lm` also accepts strings that can be coerced to formula you can use `paste` which will give the same result.

```
lm(paste(x, y, sep = '~'), data=mtcars)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use the `rlang` style quoting/unquoting, you would use.

```
y = sym("mpg")
x = sym("hp")

# alternatively
# y = expr(mpg)
# x = expr(hp)


fml = inject(!!y ~ !!x)

lm(fml, data=mtcars)
```

Comment: oh wow, thank you very much!